How exactly did Muhammad transmit the verses of the Quran to his companions?
From what I've learned, Muhammad was revealed the Quran over 23 years from angel Gabriel, and he told it to his companions who memorized it through rhythmic chants and such, and this memorization technique seems to have been common in ancient pre-islamic Arabia. Only after Muhammads death it seems that it was written down.
My question is, what were the exact techniques used to memorize the verses of the Quran. How did this work? Is there a known rhythm or way of singing or chanting them? If so, where can I learn this rhythm?

The Quran is memorized by repeating it again and again. People still do it all the time. I am not aware of anything about using chants or whatever. Also the Prophet ﵌ had the Quran written down during his lifetime, he had scribes to whom he dictated and they wrote it down.

My question is, how exactly did they repeat it and rhythm it? Where can I learn the exact technique?
